# in clojure language what <'a> really is

Tags: macros, clojure, symbols, cons

actually i am trying to perfectly understand clojure and particularly symbols

```
(def a 1)
(type a)
;;=>java.lang.Long
(type 'a)
;;=>clojure.lang.Symbol
```

I know that `type` is a function so its arguments get evaluated first so i perfectly understand why the code above work this way .In the flowing code i decided to delay the evaluation using macro

```
 (defmacro m-type [x] (type x))
 (m-type a)
 ;;==>clojure.lang.Symbol
```

and i am fine with that but what i fail to uderstand is this:

```
 (m-type 'a)
 ;;=>clojure.lang.Cons
```

why the type of 'a is a cons

Comment: User who voted to close as "Too Broad" can you justify your decision? This has a concrete and simple answer

Comment: Perhaps someone only read the title?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the character ' is interpreted by the clojure reader as a reader-macro which expands to a list containing the symbol `quote` followed by whatever follows the ', so in your call to `(m-type 'a)` the `'a` is expanding to:

```
user> (macroexpand-1 ''a)
(quote a)
```

then calling type on the list `(quote a)` which is a Cons.

This may be a bit more clear if we make the m-type macro print the arguments as it sees them while it is evaluating:

```
user> (defmacro m-type [x] (println "x is " x) (type x))
#'user/m-type
user> (m-type 'a)
x is  (quote a)
clojure.lang.Cons
```

Comment: I think the OP will still be confused by the result of (type 'a) - the call without Macro -

Comment: Thats a good point, there is both macro expansion and quoting at play in that one.

Comment: Most likely he will ask again why (type 'a) is returning clojure.lang.Symbol . But I'm not illusionist!

Comment: i am not an OP and i get it